# json foreach problem

Tags: php, json

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "caption": "www.bollywoodtune.com",
         "type": "link",
         "created_time": "2011-01-17T07:23:02+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-01-17T07:23:02+0000"
      },
...
 ]
}
```

here is the json form, how to make a foreach?
When I use

```
foreach ($data[0] as $result) {
...
}
```

it show `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in line foreach ($data[0] as $result)` Thanks.

Comment: How are you loading `$data` into PHP? You've missed out a step.

Comment: +1 for all json_decode answers, mainly for your mind reading abilities.

Comment: I find the error, `foreach ($data->date as $result)` is the problem. thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decode the json data

```
$data= json_decode($data,true);
foreach ($data as $v)
  {
  }
```

Comment: `foreach ($data as $v)` is nothing,  but `echo $data` before `$data= json_decode($data); ` I can get all the data.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `json_decode`, make sure that you pass `true` to the second operator.

For example,

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Normally, objects converted using `json_decode` will be stored as **PHP objects** which can't be iterated over. Passing `true` as the second argument makes `json_decode` convert objects to **associative arrays** instead.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do this:

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($data as $d)
{
  //stmts here
}
```

for more information about the parameters visit php manual for [json](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)